# Can pydev refactor a function call so that named arguments are used?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

For example:

```
def f(foo, bar):
 return foo + bar

answer = f(3,4)
```

What I'm looking for is some way to highlight the function call in pydev and have it automatically refactored so that it reads:

```
answer = f(foo=3, bar=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently possible. Please enter that as a feature request in the PyDev sf tracker. See: http://pydev.org/about.html for links.